# How to define a pydantic.BaseModel that allows both fixed words and a pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have the following code

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Product(BaseModel):
    name: str
    tags: list[str]  # Accepted tags: "mean", "std", "extra_<float with 1 decimal point>".
```

The `tags` is a `list` of `str`. But it only accepts certain words.

1. fixed words: `mean` and `std`.
2. flexible words: it must start with `extra_` and be followed by a float with 1 decimal point. For example `extra_1.0`, `extra_2.5`. But `extra_3.14` is not allowed.

Can you please show me how to implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [Yurii Motov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20301996/yurii-motov)

**1st solution**
You can use **Union**, **Literal**, **Annotated** and **StringConstraints**
(not **constr**, due to: [Pydantic docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.constr--__tabbed_1_1), **constr** will be deleted in 3.0 version)

```
from typing_extensions import Annotated, Union, Literal 
from pydantic import BaseModel, StringConstraints

class Product(BaseModel):
    name: str
    tags: list[Union[Literal['mean', 'std'],
                  Annotated[str, StringConstraints(pattern=r'exp\_[0-9]\.[0-9]')]]]
```

if input string doesn't match expectations this error will raise:

```
Input should be 'mean' or 'std' [type=literal_error,
input_value='template', input_type=str]...
String should match pattern 'exp\_[0-9]\.[0-9]'
[type=string_pattern_mismatch, input_value='template', input_type=str]
```

or a similar one

**2nd solution**
Also you can use **Annotated** and **Function validation** (docs: [Pydantic docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/)), see here:
My simple example:

```
def handler(s: str):
    #write the desired handler
    if(not s == 'template'):
        raise TypeError('Not valid string')
    return s

MyStr = Annotated[str, BeforeValidator(handler)]

class Product(BaseModel):
    name: str
    tags: list[MyStr]

# this will raise TypeError, because of int input
# product = Product(name = 'name', tags = [1])

# this will also raise TypeError, that inside handler
# product = Product(name = 'name', tags = ['1','template'])

# this is totally fine
product = Product(name = 'name', tags = ['template','template'])
```

**but you should rewrite handler**

Comment: It's nice solution if you don't need to describe allowed values in schema. If you do, you can specify type as `Union[Literal['mean'], Literal['std'], pattern]`, where `pattern` is a type alias for `constr(regex=r'')`. You need to write regex expression. I haven' t check it, it's just my thoughts